# React Native - WebView with Transparent background

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

Is it an option to set transparent background to WebView element?

```
<View>
   <WebView source={{uri: 'https://www.demo.io'}} style={{ backgroundColor:'transparent'}}/>
</View>
```

My HTML do ave transparent background, but it seems that the web view is still not transparent

Comment: try giving the `backgroundColor: 'transparent' ` to the `View` instead

Answer (score 9):

Yes it works if you put `style={{ backgroundColor:'transparent'}` both in WebView and in the parent View

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
  <WebView 
     source={{uri: 'https://www.demo.io'}} 
     style={{ backgroundColor:'transparent'}}
  />
</View>
```